Why does LLVM IR generate `alloca` and `store` instructions for unused variables?
I'm learning LLVM IR and noticed some seemingly redundant instructions in the generated code. For example, in the following LLVM IR:
define i32 @main() #0 {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, ptr %1, align 4
  ret i32 0
}

The corresponding C source code is:
// test.c
int main() {
    return 0;
}

and the LLVM IR is generated by
clang -Xclang -emit-llvm -S test.c -O0 -o test.ll

The first two lines (%1 = alloca i32, align 4 and store i32 0, ptr %1, align 4) allocate space for an integer and initialize it with 0, even though this variable is never used anywhere else. If I change the return value to 1, these two lines still exist. My question is: Why does LLVM generate these alloca and store instructions if the variable is unused? (And I'm pretty sure %1is not for the argc parameter).
I’m curious if there’s a specific reason for this in LLVM’s design, or if it’s part of a broader convention in IR generation. Also, since these instructions are removed at higher optimization levels, why are they included in unoptimized code?
Thank you for reading!

It's part of the general design: Make it easy to generate IR and have some passes clean that up later. So frontends generate that alloca because they're generating that part of code and at that time the alloca may be necessary. It turns out to be unnecessary a little later. The general principle is: Make life simple for frontends and their authors. Being a frontend author, you probably approve.

@arnt thanks for your reading and answering, your comment really helps :)
